# How do UV vectors blend with normal vectors?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I aim to implement a feature in Geometry Nodes where a Flow Map is utilized to adjust the growth direction of grooming patterns. However, I'm currently facing an issue where the grooming directions do not follow the surface normals of the object. Kindly seeking assistance with this problem. Many thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Keep track of the space you're operating in.  Your normal and position are in object space.  Is your input vector, provided from texture, in object space?  Probably not, because abandoning Z wouldn't make any sense in that case; you probably intend these to be tangent space vectors.  But doing math on vectors in different spaces just gets you gibberish-- you need to transform them first to be in the same space to get meaningful output.

Comment: I'm truly ashamed; my math skills are quite poor, and I honestly don't understand how to approach this at all.

Comment: If you want to do this, rather than just have somebody do it for you, you will need to know what space your flow map is in; to do that, you will need to understand coordinate spaces.  The first thing I ever read regarding coordinate spaces was at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Coordinate_Spaces_in_Blender .  That might get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will study it further. Appreciate it!